# I can't access the preference page in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, preference

I'm having trouble getting to the preference page in visual studio 2019. On windows/linux I know it's supposed to be [ file > preference ] but It's not showing under the file menu for me. I have already tried to reset all settings and it didn't work. Are there any other ways to get to the preference page in visual studio 2019 ???

Comment: Are you, perhaps, looking for "Tools -> Options" ?

Comment: There is no File->Preferences

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at:

Tools > Options > Environment > General

And then under Tools > Customize